# Moving data in an Excel spreadsheet, will I need to use VBA? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

as cliche as it sounds, long time reader, first time poster. I'm currently helping a family member out with some work and he has to sort through several thousand records and slightly change the format, obviously without some sort of automation it would take tens of hours and he asked me if I could help do it quickly. At first I thought I could, but I'm a little over my head with some of this stuff.

Basically, he has this data in this type of format:

```
Sample No 
1         Ag 20
1         Au 50
1         Cu 80
2         AG 1
2         Au 30
3         Cu 30
```

But we need the data like this:

```
Sample No. Ag Au Cu
1          20 50 80
2          1  30 -
3          -  -  30
```

At first I thought I could do it with a formula to move the data horizontally. The only problem is the missing data would preferably be filled with a '-', but in the original data given they are just left out entirely, so Im assuming I'll need VBA.

Sorry if I left anything out, but any pointers in the right direction with VBA would be incredibly handy.

Thanks

EDIT: Fixed formatting and had two numbers switched, sorry guys.

Comment: Shouldn't `50 20 80` be `20 50 80`?

Comment: Yes, again, my mistake, let me fix the OP, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Pivot Tables](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/pivottable-reports-101-HA001034632.aspx) for this.

Assuming your data is currently in a single column, you can do the following:

1. Data menu > Text To Columns, split on a space
2. With your three new columns, insert a row into A1
3. Give your three columns captions, such as Sample, Element and Size
4. Highlight your entire range, and select Data menu > Pivot Table and PivotChart report...
5. Select "Microsoft Office Excel list or database", and press "Next"
6. Select "New Worksheet" if you want the data in a new worksheet
7. From here, drop your Sample element into the left side of the table, the Element element into the top side of the table, and the Size element into the middle of the table.

You won't have dashes for your missing data, but this should do what you want.

Comment: + 1 You beat me to it. I had to discard the answer. Though you took a slightly longer route. :)

Comment: For some awful reason I was trying to do it in VBA at first, and then, *lightbulb*

Comment: I know how it feels. It has happened to me in the past. :D

Comment: Disregard the comment I deleted, the duplicates were not necessary. Thanks again.

Comment: @DouglasQuaid - glad it worked! If you check the green checkbox next to the answer, other users will know the question has been answered.